# Compare Object won't return Correct Values

Tags: powershell

I'm running compare object on two lists. The `$distros` list contains an object with the name **MDM**, and the `$adgroups` list does not have an object with that name.

Why does the compare object not return an input object with name MDM and the <= side indicator?

```
PS C:\Users\ME> $distros | ?{$_.name -like "*MDM*"}

Name                           DisplayName                    GroupType                      PrimarySmtpAddress            
----                           -----------                    ---------                      ------------------            
MDM                            MDM                            Universal                      MDM@contoso.com  

PS C:\Users\ME> $adgroups | ?{$_.name -like "*MDM*"}

PS C:\Users\ME> Compare-Object ($distros | select name) ($adgroups | select Name)

InputObject                                                   SideIndicator                                                
-----------                                                   -------------                                                
@{Name=UAD}                                                   <=                                                           
@{Name=UAT Funders}                                           <=                                                           
@{Name=Underwriting Managers}                                 <=
```

Using `Compare-Object ($distros | select -expandproperty Name) ($adgroups | select -expandproperty Name` worked. Thanks to Matt in comments.

Comment: Perhaps something like this `Compare-Object ($distros | select -expandproperty name) ($adgroups | select -expandproperty Name)`

Comment: Also we don't see how `$distros` or `$adgroups` are created. For all we know `$adgroups` doesnt have a name property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this instead

```
Compare-Object ($distros | select -expandproperty name) ($adgroups | select -expandproperty Name)
```

`-expandproperty name` will just return a string array of `name`s instead of the object array with name properties. Obviously `Compare-Object` will work with complex objects but expanding the `$distros` names and `$adgroups` names make the output cleaner.

You could aslo try something like this too which is more terse!

```
Compare-Object $distros $adgroups -property Name
```